# How do I know which method will be called?

Tags: r, methods

If I type `methods(print)` I get a long list of methods.

For an object of class `data.frame`, `print.data.frame` will be called.

It's not always so simple though:

```
hw <- "hello world"
class(hw) # [1] "character"
```

There is no `print.character` method. How do I know which method is called  when executing `print(hw)`?

Comment: If there isn't one defined it will use the default method

Comment: `print.default` exists, but `[.default` doesn't, how do I know which method is called by `c("hello","world")[2]` ?

Comment: Btw, Did you start checking this after seeing `strict` package?

Comment: No, I just sometimes want to be what's in the source code :), and be sure I understand what's going on when building my own methods.

Answer (score 4):

Turn debugging on for print and then run your example:

```
> debug(print)
> print("hello")
debugging in: print("hello")
debug: UseMethod("print")
Browse[2]>  <---------------------------- press Enter to step forward
debugging in: print.default("hello")  <-- this is the method that gets called
debug: {
    noOpt <- missing(digits) && missing(quote) && missing(na.print) && 
        missing(print.gap) && missing(right) && missing(max) && 
        missing(useSource) && missing(...)
    .Internal(print.default(x, digits, quote, na.print, print.gap, 
        right, max, useSource, noOpt))
}
```

Comment: it does work in this case thanks, with a call to `undebug(print)` in the end or you're stuck forever (and as a sidenote `debugonce` doesn't work because it needs to debug twice). It also doesn't work if I try : `debug('[');c("hello","world")[2]`.

Comment: It isn't necessary to continue if all you are interested in is to find which method was called which is what the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read Hadley's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#base-types) and the chapter on objects? It might not give you the whole answer, but fundamentally what you're experiencing is the difference between method dispatch in C and regular S3 behaviour.

`[` isn't really an R function, it's a C function and the decision of what method to use is done in C. That doesn't mean you can't create an S3 method for `[` (or `sum`, `+`, `[<-` and other .Primitive functions), but when you do it's more like you're making a wrapper/preprocess for the C function, which R will dispatch, before the ultimate decision is made by the C function based on classes defined separate from your regular (and extensible) R classes.

Or at least that's how I've understood it.

Comment: It's helping a lot thanks. So to connect the dots (and please anyone correct me if I'm wrong), S3 generics written in C don't call `UseMethod`, I can still use `methods` on them and try to guess, but if I can't find it this way I'd have to dig into the C code and look for `DispatchGroup` or `DispatchOrEval` calls. I can recognize them by calling `pryr:ftype` on them, it will describe them as primitives. These are exceptions though, and not the functions one usually wants to investigate in the first place.

Comment: For the other cases, as long as `my_function` is a S3 generic, if `my_function.my_class` doesn't exist, and `my_class` is handled by the function, then `my_function.default` always exists and will always be called for these cases.